# Reportlab mix static text and paragraphs

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

I am trying to get started in reportlab. I know how to add strings, lines etc. Now I want to be able to combine static text with paragraphs and the static text needs to be in specific position. Sorry for the indentation errors.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import Image, SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer,    
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY


PAGE_HEIGHT=defaultPageSize[1]; PAGE_WIDTH=defaultPageSize[0]

Story = []

p = "This is a paragraph"



last_name = "John"
first_name = "Doe"
dosuren = "02-03-2016"



def generate_report(last_name, first_name, dosuren):
    pdf_file_name = last_name + first_name + "_" + dosuren + ".pdf"

    c= canvas.Canvas(pdf_file_name, pagesize=letter)

    c.setFont('Times-Bold', 12,leading=None )
    c.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2.0, PAGE_HEIGHT-108,  "REPORT")

##### Static Text ############


c.setFont('Times-Bold', 12, leading=None)
c.drawString(30, 320, "Subject INfo:")

c.setFont('Times-Roman', 12, leading=None)
c.drawString(30, 380, "Subject info2:")

##Paragraph###
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))
Story.append(Paragraph(p, styles["Justify"]))


c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

From your requirements it is clear that you are looking for `PageTemplate`, it allows you to first draw some fixed elements on the page and later add `Paragraph`'s and other `Flowable`'s to it.

A quick example would look like this:

```
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate, PageTemplate, Frame, Paragraph

def draw_static(canvas, doc):
    # Save the current settings
    canvas.saveState()

    # Draw the static stuff
    canvas.setFont('Times-Bold', 12, leading=None)
    canvas.drawCentredString(200, 200, "Static element")

    # Restore setting to before function call
    canvas.restoreState()

# Set up a basic template
doc = BaseDocTemplate('test.pdf')

# Create a Frame for the Flowables (Paragraphs and such)
frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height, id='normal')

# Add the Frame to the template and tell the template to call draw_static for each page
template = PageTemplate(id='test', frames=[frame], onPage=draw_static)

# Add the template to the doc
doc.addPageTemplates([template])

# All the default stuff for generating a document
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
story = []

P = Paragraph('This is a paragraph', styles["Normal"])

story.append(P)
doc.build(story)
```